# When will $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] be removed?

Tags: php

How long the uploaded file will be stored somewhere in a temporary folder with the name `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

Comment: doesn't matter. Ajax is also a HTTP request. No difference how server gets request, web form or ajax form. It still is a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

it get deleted once the `PHP` script it was submitted too is finished running